# How to tell when data through a pipe has ended

Tags: python, linux, pipe

In my python program I have two `subprocesses` interconnected by a `pipe` and with one connected to `stdin` and the other connected to `stdout`. My problem is that when the data flow ends the subprocesses hang until I press `ctrl+c`. It looks to me like the subprocesses are being held open my the pipe. If I could tell when the data flowing through the pipe I could close it manually.

```
def write(tag_name):
    p_r, p_w = os.pipe()
    pv = subprocess.Popen('pv', stdin=None, stdout=p_w)
    dd = subprocess.Popen('dd bs=64k of=/dev/nst0'.split(), stdin=p_r, stdout=None)
    dd.wait()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `os.pipe()`, you can pass subprocess `stdout` directly to the other process `stdin`, like this:

```
def write(tag_name):
    pv = subprocess.Popen('pv', stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    dd = subprocess.Popen('dd bs=64k of=/dev/nst0'.split(), stdin=pv.stdout, stdout=None)
    dd.wait()
```

When first command ends, the pipe is broken (as opposed to `os.pipe()` which need to be closed manually), so it ends the second command as well and the script can continue/end.

I have tested a simple pipe command and with `os.pipe()` it blocks at the end as you described, but exited when first process ended with my modifications.

Comment: I'm geting `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` on the `pv` line.

Comment: Looking at the python manual `subprocess.STDOUT` can only be used as the argument to `Popen.stderr`. Passing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` works as you said, though.

Comment: sorry, typo!! fixed to `subprocess.PIPE`

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-blocking solution here.
Take a look at my solution: https://github.com/vesellov/bitdust.devel/blob/master/system/nonblocking.py

And you can call it this way (did not tested the code):

```
import nonblocking, time
p = nonblocking.Popen('pv'.split(), shell=True, )
p.make_nonblocking()
while 1:
    if p.state() == nonblocking.PIPE_CLOSED:
        # pipe closed, stop
        return break
    if p.state() == nonblocking.PIPE_READY2READ:
        newchunk = p.recv(1024)
        if newchunk == '':
            # EOF reached, stop
            break
        # do something with the data here
        # you can send it to second stream
    try:
       time.sleep(0.01)
    except KeyboardInterrup:
       break
```

So when you call dd.wait() it will block, that is why your Ctrl-C not working. You need to deal with this manually....  non-blocking streaming is not a trivial story in Python.  Check-out [Twisted project](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/process.html), you can find a lot of cool stuff :-)

Comment: Interesting solution, only downside is that it has a bandwidth limited to 100KB/s. In my case the `dd.wait()` isn't stopping the `Ctrl-C`, in fact pressing `Ctrl-C` causes the pipe to be garbage collected and the subprocesses to exit cleanly.

Comment: Yeah, you can adjust `time.sleep()` interval as you need.